# Determine \DateTime has inferred a day in constructor

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to make user-input accept a date to limit searching.  I use the following:

```
try {
    $begin = new \DateTime($range['begin']);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $begin = null;
}
```

If the date fails to construct, then the query (not shown) is not modified.

Occasionally the users enter just a month, and it would be obvious then that the user wants to search between the first and last day of the month, and I might modify the query in a different way.

Unfortunately php infers, without other specification that the user means the first of the month.  Is there any way to determine if this has happened?  Another way to ask this question is how does one determine that a user has supplied a valid month without a day and distinguish that from supplying a date with first day of the month that leverages the myriad formats DateTime automatically interprets?

My first pass used date_parse, but that also infers the date.

Comment: The [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) constructor accepts a lot of formats for the input string. It does its best to extract a date & time from the provided input. The rules are explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). To achieve your goal you should do a parse yourself before passing the input string to [`DateTime`], to detect the special situations you want to handle (when the user enters only the month name, f.e.).

Comment: You're not providing much information here. What does the input look like? Can't you just check the input format and change it accordingly?

Comment: i prefer simple select field where user can choose one value from defined optons list [today, yesterday, 1 week, 2 weeks, etc] so next you can create valid DateTime object if need, or of need not exact latest periods than its better to use datepicker with range functionality where one is start date and second value end date

Comment: @miken32 The point was to use the myriad formats DateTime already accepts rather than reinventing them

Answer (score -1):

better always to know format of input value, so then you can simple convert to datetime object, for example:

```
$inputFieldValue = '22/02/2017';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $inputFieldValue);
if ($date instanceof \DateTime) {
    echo 'input is valid date, do what you need';
} else {
    echo 'input is not valid date';
}
```

more documentation http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php